# Using CURL in a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, curl, libcurl

I am trying to create a DLL that uses the CURL library.

The docs say that **curl_global_init()** must be called once and before anything else.

My question is, what is correct ? to have an **Init()** function exported by the DLL that calls **curl_global_init()** and must be called initially, or call **curl_global_init()** in DllMain() ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging more into it, and following advice from [the CURL website](http://curl.haxx.se) it appears that the correct procedure is to have a **static global object** whose constructor calls curl_global_init() and whose destructor calls curl_global_cleanup().

Answer (score 1):

Neither I would say. Just export curl_global_init() and require your client to call that.